# Rigidbody not stopping instantly when setting its velocity to 0

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my player's movement snappy, in a 3D environment, using forces. I tried a couple of things, but judging by how my player reacts in-game, I think I'm missing some piece of information.

```
public Rigidbody rb;

public float acceleration = 500f;
public UnityEngine.ForceMode forceMode = ForceMode.Impulse;

void Update() {
    rb.AddRelativeForce(new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * acceleration * Time.deltaTime, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * acceleration * Time.deltaTime), forceMode);
    rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
}
```

First of all, how come this code still allows me to move my player around? Resetting the velocity to 0 every frame should prevent it from moving, shouldn't it? I guess the force is still being applied on the subsequent frames even if the velocity is constantly set to 0?

How should I use forces to get really snappy movement, where when I stop pressing UP, the force applied on the Z axis is "stopped"?

Comment: You should never use Update to do anything physic based. Use FixedUpdate instead

Comment: Why do you want to `rb.AddRelativeForce` and right after it set `rb.velocity = Vector3.zero`?

Comment: @derHugo It was more of a test, to see if I understood how things worked, as I have trouble stopping my object, after applying a force on it. So I was like "Im going to reset the velocity just after applying the force, to see what it does". And I was hoping that my object would not be moving. But it is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something important to note is the [Order of Execution](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) of unity scripts and functionality. The way that physics works is actually a bit more nuanced, and is likely causing your issue.

A quick fix to your problem would likely be something like putting your rigidbody to sleep after setting the velocity to 0:

```
rb.Sleep();
```

This ensures that the execution of internal physics update does not affect this rigidbody any further. Typically you do not need need to manually handle Sleep() and WakeUp() for rigidbodies as they are automatically called based on collisions or velocity thresholds, but in this case it will prevent the queued AddForce from impacting the RB after its velocity is zeroed out.

Comment: Thanks. You're right it's related to the order. I found another thread where they mention that AddForce is delayed. But anyway, the root of my issue was really "dumb". GetAxis doesn't return 0 as soon as the button is released... That's why my character was sliding... Using GetAxisRaw just solved everything.

Comment: Ahh, it was a combination of the GetAxis smoothing your input AND the internal physics getting delayed? Tricky, but good job @Robin !